# QTreeView parent item style

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtreeview

How could I make the top-level items of a QTreeView look like "Layouts" or "Spacers" in the capture image. [image: style example]

is there any way to add separator to the QListView?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom delegate to achieve this. Therefore, you need to re implement paint method.